# retornar tinyint como boleano em json encode

Tags: php

Faço um fetchall com pdo no banco e recebo o resultado corretamente, porem os valores boleanos são salvos em tinyint no banco, e recebo eles em 1 e 0, então quando faço json encode, ele me retorna 0 e 1, queria retornar true ou false.
tentei fazer um foreach para converter mas assim ele retorna só a linha que converti.

```
$usermail = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_USER');
$senha = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_PW');

$sql = new Sql();
$user =  new Usuario();
$autenticado = $user->login($usermail[0],$senha[0]);

if ($autenticado) {
    $resultado = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1",array(
        ":EMAIL"=>$usermail[0]
    ));
    foreach( $resultado as $row ) {
        $array[] = array('liberadoexercicio' => (bool)$row['liberadoexercicio']);
    }
    $response = json_encode(array_shift($array),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    return $response;
}else{
    return $response->withStatus(401);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é que basicamente o que você está fazendo é capturar todas as informações da tabela `tb_alunos` > Salvando apenas os dados `liberadoexercicio` na variável `$array` > Apagando o primeiro registro com `array_shift` e exibindo o json na tela.

Você pode fazer o seguinte para retornar os dados como `bool`

```
<?php

$resultado = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1",array(
    ":EMAIL"=>$usermail[0]
));

/* Se você quiser retornar apenas o campo `liberadoexercicio` utilize a query abaixo (é melhor quanto a performance) */
/* SELECT liberadoexercicio FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1 */

foreach( $resultado as &$row ) {
    $row["liberadoexercicio"] = (bool)$row["liberadoexercicio"];

    //$row["liberadoexercicio"] = $row["liberadoexercicio"] == 1; // Outra forma
}

echo json_encode($resultado);
```

> O **&** quer dizer que `$row` é uma referencia a uma variável, como não sei seu nível de orientação a objetos, vou deixar o [link para leitura](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: daonde ta saindo $alunos?

Comment: Entendi, é o resultado da consulta, funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar quando seta o array, utilizando uma condicional (if, switch, ternário)

```
$usermail = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_USER');
$senha = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_PW');

$sql = new Sql();
$user =  new Usuario();
$autenticado = $user->login($usermail[0],$senha[0]);

if ($autenticado) {
    $resultado = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1",array(
        ":EMAIL"=>$usermail[0]
    ));
    foreach( $resultado as $row ) {
        // modo 1
        if($row['liberadoexercicio'] == 1)
            $res = true;
        else
            $res = false;
        $array[] = array('liberadoexercicio' => $res);  
        // modo 2
        $array[] = array(
            'liberadoexercicio' => ($row['liberadoexercicio'] == 1) ? true : false
        );
    }
    $response = json_encode(array_shift($array),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    return $response;
}else{
    return $response->withStatus(401);
}
```

Comment: ele retorna só essa linha "liberadoexercicio", quero exibir todo o resultado, alterando este 1 para true por exemplo